# How to change hint text in Snipcart's payment form

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, snipcart

I am using **snipcart** in my react web app. Reading their [docs](https://docs.snipcart.com/v3/sdk/api#theme) I found out that I cannot override the css of the payment form because that payment form is being loaded in an iframe and to customize it , I have to use their javascript sdk like this:

```
 Snipcart.api.theme.customization.registerPaymentFormCustomization({
                label: {
                    color: '#fff',
                },
                legend: {
                    color: '#fff'
                },
            });
```

Now this is working great for legend and label elements,  but there's one  paragraph in snipcart form as well which has class **test-card-hint**. And I can't find any way to override it. I have tried passing down following values:

```
 Snipcart.api.theme.customization.registerPaymentFormCustomization({
                label: {
                    color: '#fff',
                },
                legend: {
                    color: '#fff'
                },
                p:{
                   color:"#fff"
                }
            });
```

```
 Snipcart.api.theme.customization.registerPaymentFormCustomization({
                label: {
                    color: '#fff',
                },
                legend: {
                    color: '#fff'
                },
                ".test-card-hint":{
                    color: '#fff'
                 }
            });
```

Also tried using sibling selector like **legend ~ p** but to no avail.

You can see in the image below that only styles for label and legend are being generated.

[image: No changes reflected unless its legend or label]

Here is the html markup for the form:
[image: Html Markup of Snipcart Form]

Does anyone know of a workaround to this? Is it possible to override css for this particular element at all?

Comment: I would suggest you to send a message to Snipcart. You can do it here https://snipcart.com/contact-feedback. I also asked them a few times about the customization and they have responded me with how to do it.

Comment: Thank you. I just did that.Will update if they reply.